# Use commitizen on a code-agnostic project

Tags: commitizen

I would like to start incorporating commitizen in my repository; however, implementation seems to revolve around adding a js dependency on the repository, and calling it independently (and enforcing it with a hook).

My project currently is python, but that's besides the point - it seems to me that commitizen should be able to be orthogonal to the underlying repository.

However, I don't understand how would that be possible. Maybe the instructions don't exist, or I have not yet separated them from the "main usage path".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question @Stavros. I have recently been playing with it and started to have the same question. I tried to find an answer from its documentation https://commitizen-tools.github.io/commitizen/ but could not find it. Based on my testing, it seems to me that it only supports Python projects. However by the way it works, it should be able to support all Git projects.

Comment: I think the confusion stems from the fact that multiple orgs/projects use the same `commitizen` name. The one you linked to is for Python, and it has slightly different functionality compared to http://commitizen.github.io/cz-cli/.